# Example of null tensor product

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products

> Does there exists a commutative noetherian ring $R$ with unit which has two ideals $I_1$ and $I_2$ such that $I_1\otimes_R I_2=0$ and $I_1I_2\neq 0$?

I've tryed to use a quotient of the multivariable polynomial ring but i can't find an example. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

There is an onto homomorphism $I_1\otimes_R I_2\to I_1I_2$ for $I_1,I_2$ ideals of $R$.